# Browser-based RPG: Using sessions to store player data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a browser Role Playing Game in JavaScript, HTML5 (canvas). I'd like to store player data in a MySQL database using sessions.

I've created a login system and it seems to be recognizing me when I log in.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome back, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
    header("Location: php/Login.php");
}
```

Would I store data into a database using session variables as well? How do I associate the data with the username stored in the current session? Would I create session variables to store each item? That doesn't seem logical. When the user presses "save", it will call a MySQL function to load that data into a table.

Comment: Your question seems to be about how the PHP session system works and is best used and isn't specific to games.

Comment: Also something we need to know: Is this specific to a certain mechanic, do you have any example code for this mechanic such as the item storing you mentioned. Using any extra example code along with the behaviour you are trying to achieve - we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

When your login function (presumably) reads the username and login data to validate the user, it can also retrieve the userid or whatever you're using as the primary key for the user table (you are using a primary key, right?) Then you can store that key in the session itself for use in subsequent read and write operations.